# Optimal OS and ROS for raspberry pi4

Tags: pi-4

What's the optimal OS and ROS setup for configuring a LiDAR and an accelerator on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?... how are you connecting it all together?

Comment: I aim to create a system capable of performing tasks like 3D maping and object detection....and i want to know what is the OS and ROS compatible with the raspberry pi 4 if you have any idea?